# Erro IllegalArgumentException ao apresentar dados no aplicativo

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando apresentar tudo que foi gravado em meu app durante a execução, porem apresenta o erro abaixo:

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.projeto....}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

LivrosActivity:

```
public class LivrosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_livros);

    ListView lista;

    BancoControlador control = new BancoControlador(getBaseContext());
    Cursor cursor = control.carregaDados();

    String[] nomeCampos = new String[]{CriaBanco.id, CriaBanco.livro};
    int[] idViews = new int[] {R.id.idLivro, R.id.nomeLivro};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.activity_main, cursor, nomeCampos, idViews, 0);
    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewLivros);
    lista.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

Método que atribuir os valores:

```
    public Cursor carregaDados(){

     Cursor cursor;
     String[] campos = {banco.id,banco.livro};
     db = banco.getReadableDatabase();
     cursor = db.query(banco.tabela, campos, null, null, null, null, null);

     if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
     }
     db.close();
     return cursor;
 }
```

XML:

```
   <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listViewLivros"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

   <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idLivro"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="ID" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nomeLivro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Livro" />

</GridLayout>
```

Método OnCreate - OnUpgrade:

```
public CriaBanco(Context context) {
    super(context, nomebanco, null, versao, null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE "+tabela+"( "
            +id+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
            +livro+" text(40)"
            +")";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+tabela);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Comment: O erro ocorre pois não achou o campo **_id** na tabela! Poderia colocar o código que cria a tabela, e o método **carregaDados()** ? Ajudaria muito! Obrigado!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski O método carregaDados está entre a activity e o XML.. Estou informando o ID ao declarar o vetor String campos[], caso queira, posso editar o post com o código das demais classes..

Comment: No seu **SQLiteOpenHelper** tem um método **public void onCreate(final SQLiteDatabase db)** que cria as tabelas no banco de dados, certo? veja se quando você cria a tabela livro você declara o **_id** mais ou menos assim : **CREATE TABLE livro ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, nome TEXT) )**

Comment: Desinstala o app do seu device e roda de novo que resolve, ou muda a versão do seu banco local.

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski Realizei os dois procedimentos acima, mas nenhum resolveu.. editei minha pergunta com o método onCreate.. estou conseguindo cadastrar normalmente, porem o problema esta no momento de carregar os dados.

Comment: @GabrielHenrique No método `carregaDados()` tem o `array` de campos, o que retorna nessa parte o comando `banco.id`?

Comment: @IgorMello esta sendo recuperado o valor da variavel id:                    public static String id = "id";

Comment: Melhor via chat para não ficar muito extenso os comentários -> http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42919/discussion

Answer (score 1):

acho q seu erro esta aqui

```
  String sql = "CREATE TABLE "+tabela+"( "
        +id+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
        +livro+" text(40)"
        +")";
```

pelo q reparei seu id e uma variavel como esse campo nao devera ser mudado vc pode trocar por _id , outra coisa toda vez q vc iniciar esse projeto o onCreate ira criar uma nova table se vc quiser evitar isso use if exist, assim a table so sera criada uma unica vez , tente usar esse query aqui;

```
 String sql = "create table if not exist "+tabela+"( _id integer primary key autoincrement,livro text(40))";
```

creio q o campo livro tbm nao pode ser mudado , depois de criado abre o Android Device Monitor e olha a estrutura da sua table para conferir se esta correta , tenha cretesa que os campos estao com o nome certo a path da sqlite no Android Device Monitor seria

```
 /data/data/com.package.appname/databases
```

PS: penso q esse seria seu problema , teria que ter mais detalhes do seu codigo para saber.